# Passing mark qualification with Python collection

Tags: python

I need to classify a number (an exam mark) and return a string with:

```
A+=10, 10>A>9, 9>B>7, 7>C>5, 5>D
```

So if my mark is a '8.5', it will return 'B'.

The problem is that I have to use a collection to solve this, and as I am a newbie with python, I don't know what type of collection I should use.

Comment: Hint: look up *bisection*.

Comment: Wouldn't an 8.5 be a B?

Comment: Damn, you are right chepner!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (among other help documents).  We'll help you fix existing code, but we don't write or design it for you.  At least give us a short description of which collections you've considered, and where you're confused.  You may have to review your class materials or an on-line tutorial to get there.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by collection?

Comment: A list or a dictionary, but i dont know how to get ranges in a list and compare the number with the list

Comment: @ajay, a collection is a Python module.  https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html

Comment: @Prune `collections` is a module that defines several different container types.

Comment: have to use a collection sounds like a school/university homework

Comment: @chepner -- thanks; time-slicing here.

Comment: @Panoremux, consider which of these types serves your needs: an ordered list of cut-offs that you can test.

Comment: @colidyre yep, you're right

Comment: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Martijn Pieters actually has a great suggestion (first comment). Have you looked at the "other examples" section of the help page for ````bisect````? You will find a VERY useful code block. He is the only one who has been close to giving you the answer you need. Here is a link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples

Comment: @KivakWolf Now i see, im gona take a look at it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any collection/container that would be suitable for this type of continuous range checking. I'd use an `if` statement:

```
def letter_grade(mark):
    if mark >= 10:
        return "A+"
    elif 9 < mark < 10:
        return "A"
    elif 7 < mark <= 9:
        return "B"
    elif 5 < mark <= 7:
        return "C"
    else:
        return "D"
```

If you knew that `mark` were a discrete value (say, an integer between 0 and 10), a dictionary would be correct:

```
# Something like these. A list can already be indexed by integers,
# or you can create a dictionary that is also indexed by integers.
>>> marks_list = ["D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A+"]
>>> marks_dict = dict(enumerate(marks_list))
>>> marks[9]
'A'
```

Comment: Ty for your response, yes C and D reversed ,my fault :(. As i need to use collection/container to solve this, would be correct to change the float number to an integer and then assign it a mark?

Comment: You can't enumerate all floats, though. All you can do is store the boundaries in a dictionary, but that's a pretty artificial use for a container. You would still need an `if` statement like the one above to check the mark against each key in the dictionary, for instance.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help man, i really appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP wants a solution driven using a container rather than a function containing a control structure (like an `if`). @Martijn Pieters added a great comment as the first post it it seemed to be overlooked. [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples) is the key.

First you need to create a list of breakpoints:

```
breakpoints = [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This indicates minimum values for the grade letters (D, C, B, and A respectively). 'F' is a special case because it fills in for any value less than 60, so that is added into the grade letter list as the first element. You made the grade letter list like this:

```
grades = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

Finally, you use the `bisect` to get the index of the closest minimum value of at least the `score` and use it as the index for the grade:

```
score = 8.5
print grades[bisect( breakpoints, score )]   # outputs 'B'
```

Altogether, here is the combined code block with imports:

```
import bisect

breakpoints = [6, 7, 8, 9]
grades = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
score = 8.5
print grades[bisect.bisect( breakpoints, score )]   # outputs 'B'
```

There is no need to make your own function to create this when you have wonderful built-in methods already.